# StringBuilder vs Ropes

Tags: java, stringbuilder, ropes

Good morning,

I am writing a language parser, and am looking for the best structure to use for a rollback cache which currently does the following:

- When requesting a new character from the stream, the character is added to the cache, in case a rollback is requested.
- When a rollback is requested, go back to a certain point in the cache so that when another character is requested, it gets it from there instead.
- When a token is found, remove everything in the rollback cache up to the current position.

So in short, I would love to know which you feel to be the best data structure for:

- Priority 1: appending characters (codePoints would be a welcome addition)
- Priority 2: Doing a substring (such as StringBuilder.delete(...)) on the data structure (or clearing completely)
- Priority 3: Being able to create a string of the cache (e.g. StringBuilder.toString())

I hope to hear from you soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, for such a specialised use and with possible performance and resource constraints, I'd implement my own buffer from primitives. I think it's more trouble adapting existing structures. Of course, if it didn't hurt, I'd try to conform to the well known relevant interfaces, such as `CharSequence`, `Appendable`, `List`, etc.

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure i'd know where to start! Should I look at the Ropes implementation and make my own workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a combination of a StringBuilder and [`PushbackReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html) will give you what you need.  Use the StringBuilder to accumulate characters and create token Strings, and the PushbackReader's `mark` and `reset` methods to implement rollback.

Alternatively, pre-read the entire input file as a String and then implement the tokenizer by indexing the String and taking substrings.

Comment: I am currently calling this from within an abstracted BufferedReader which allows me to create the `mark()` and `reset()` methods myself (I needed multiple marks, with a non-finite rollback buffer).

I originally had a BufferedReader which read in the code line by line, but this got ousted for two reasons, one that the code could all be on one line, and two because I wanted this rollback class to be extensible and work with the other two languages I have in development.